# Why I got user name Subscriber at Viber chat API?

Tags: viber, viber-api

When users subscribe to my Viber PA I make a request to `https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/get_user_details`
And get back strange user.name

```
[user] => Array
    (
        [id] => ***
        [name] => Subscriber
        [avatar] => http://dl-media.viber.com/1/share/2/long/bots/generic-avatar%402x.png
        [primary_device_os] => iOS 12.0.1
        [api_version] => 7
        [viber_version] => 9.9.1.28
        [device_type] => iPhone7,2
    )
```

Subscriber? And it is not only one user!
What is it? Any suggessions?

Comment: same problem here

Comment: same problem to me

Answer (score 1):

You should **turn on** this setting in Viber app for every Viber user who has this problem:

*Privacy - Personal Data - Allow Content Personalization*

Comment: How can I turn this on? Is API allow to do this?

Comment: @ПавелЗорин I think you can't turn on this setting through API or bypass it somehow. If Viber user turned this setting off you would get 'Subscriber' instead of his name.